# MongoDB aggregate match on previous stage result

Tags: mongodb, conditional-statements, match, aggregate, pipeline

I am new to MongoDB and I am not sure if this is possible, but I thought I would ask.

I have a collection of documents that are defined as follows:

```
{
    "_id": string
    "Reviews": [{
        "Ratings": numeric,
        "Author": string,
        "ReviewID": string,
        "Date": ISODate()
    }],
    "Restaurant": {
        "ID": string,
        "Name": string,
        "URL": string,
        "Address": string
    }
}
```

what I would like to do is to compute the average rating for all restaurants, and then get the ones that have a higher rating than XYZ restaurant.

For example:

To compute the average I use the following query:

```
db.reviews.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$Reviews"},
    {$group:{_id:"$Restaurant.Name", AvgOverallRating:{$avg:"$Reviews.Rating"}}},
    {$match: {_id: {$ne:null}}}
)
```

Which yields:

```
{ "_id" : "ABC Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.9 }
{ "_id" : "DEF Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.4 }
{ "_id" : "GHI Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.5 }
{ "_id" : "JKL Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 3.0 }
{ "_id" : "MNO Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 3.2 }
{ "_id" : "PQR Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 3.7 }
{ "_id" : "STU Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.8 }
{ "_id" : "XYZ Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.2 }
```

Then in the same query, I would like to match based on the XYZ average rating.

```
db.reviews.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$Reviews"},
    {$group:{_id:"$HotelInfo.Name", AvgOverallRating:{$avg:"$Reviews.Ratings.Overall"}}},
    {$match: {_id: {$ne:null}}},
    {$match: {"AvgOverallRating": {$gte: 4.2}}}
)
```

To get this:

```
{ "_id" : "ABC Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.9 }
{ "_id" : "DEF Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.4 }
{ "_id" : "GHI Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.5 }
{ "_id" : "STU Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.8 }
{ "_id" : "XYZ Restaurant", "AvgOverallRating" : 4.2 }
```

Here I specify the rating to be greater than or equal to 4.2. However, I would like to use one of the values that the "$group" stage has computed. (e.g. the rating of restaurant XYZ instead of 4.2). I want it to be dynamic so when I run this query in the future it changes based on XYZ's average rating.

Is it possible to do this in one aggregate query?

If not, how can I use multiple queries to do this?

Comment: To get a better visual of your issue, you can post your sample document from the collection and the output you are expecting and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath I just updated the post based on your suggestions.

Comment: Aggregation pipeline works that each documents in the collection are iterated once, so I'm not sure whether we can achieve your scenario of picking a dynamic average value and pass it to the same collection on the aggregation pipeline. Please see  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Comment: @ClementAmarnath since you are suggesting it is not possible. Can you suggest a way to do so even with two different/separate queries?